# doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.` and i can't update php version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got this error:

> doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version
>   (7.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.

And I can not update the PHP version, So how to solve it

Comment: PHP 7.0 is end of life and is not supported anymore. In order to keep the internet save it is wise to update your php version version. Here are the supported versions and time tables of support for [php](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: Install a lower version of `doctrine/inflector`...

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version of doctrine/inflector using composer

`composer require vendor/package:version`

for example:

`composer require doctrine/inflector:1.2.0` (this will work with php 7.0)

> **Side note:** PHP 7.0 is end of life and is not supported anymore.